# Permanently hide "cookie policy" banner with session variable

Tags: php, jquery, session-variables

Ok so my issue is as follows:

I have a cookie policy banner that loads at startup. I have since programmed a "hide" feature with jquery which fades the banner away when the text is clicked. All works fine however, I cannot figure out how to keep it hidden as I navigate the website (the banner re appears as you change pages on the site).

I assume this issue is solved with a session variable that is instantiated when I click "hide" ?

I can't however figure out where to place this code nor how to go about it.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cookie-text2").click(function(){
    $("#cookie-container").fadeOut();   
              <?php $_SESSION['noCookPol']= true;?> 
  });
});
```

What I wanted to do here was to instantiate the session variable when this jquery function is used however this approach (obviously I have done it wrong) appears to instantiate the variable regardless of whether or not it has been clicked.

1. Where would I instantiate this variable ?
2. When using my "if" statement (that would be PHP right ?), what code would I use to permanently hide the div in question ?

Something like:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['noCookPol'] == true) {  

//hide div

}?>
```

Comment: When you say cookie, are you storing a cookie that you are fetching in jquery and testing against? Cause if so once the banner is clicked then just set it.

Comment: Use a cookie or session variable

Comment: It *sounds* like you're more comfortable with HTML/JavaScript than PHP so just use `document.cookie` in JavaScript : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments this is more of Javascript question.
But a solution in plain javascript could be:

```
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 365); // 365 is a number of days
document.cookie="cookiePopup=accept; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
```

Then all you have to do is write an if statement to check if that cookie was set.

Answer (score -1):

I would use jQuery's [cookie](https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) plugin.

Set it

```
$.cookie('mycookie', 'valueOfCookie')
```

Comment: That's done the trick thanks. The problem with setting a session was it was requiring me to mess around with ajax and php (which I have zero experience with).

Comment: @SafetyFish this is using a cookie not a session and the answer still is applicable to the question.